# Where I can get the words of Dhanvantari Gayatri Mantra?

Tags: mantras, gayatri-mantra, dhanvantari

I was listening to " Dhanvantari Gayatri Mantra" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ajQOxVA3ak video.

Would like to know the words, but I did not find it. Even though I found few, it's looks little different
https://lifegivingmantras.blogspot.com/2009/10/dhanvantari-mantras.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dhanwantari Gayatri Mantras

> "Om tat purushaaya vidmahae Amritha kalasa hastaaya dheemahi Tanno
> Dhanvantri prasodayaat"
>
> "Om aadivaidhyaaya vidmahae Arogya anugrahaaya dheemahi Tanno
> dhanvantri prasodayaat"
>
> "ॐम् तत् पुरुशाय विद्मह​ए आम्रिथ कलस हस्ताय धेएमहि टन्नो ढन्वन्त्रि
> प्रसोदयात्"
>
> "ॐम् आदिव्ऐध्याय विद्मह​ए आरोग्य अनुग्रहाय धेएमहि टन्नो धन्वन्त्रि
> प्रसोदयात्"
>
> [Dhanwantari Gayatri Mantras](https://wiralfeed.wordpress.com/2015/12/12/dhanvantari-mantra/)

or

May be you are looking for this one below:

> “Om Vasudevaya Vidmahe Vaidhyarajaya Dhimahi Tanno Dhanvantri Prachodayat”

Also, from [here](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/G%C4%81yatri_Mantras_of_Several_Gods) you can find all Gayatri mantra

Comment: I am looking for mantra which improves the health conditions. Thank you

Comment: @deepak  you got mantra from this answer or not ?

Comment: Yes I got the answer, Thanks. sorry for posting new question in same post. I will create new question. Thanks again

Comment: @deepak welcome bro

Comment: I have updated your answer with better formatting, and dead-links repaired. Feel free to roll back the edit, if you didn't like it. :)