# Dhanwantari Gayatri Mantra

Tags: mantras, gayatri-mantra, dhanvantari

I have found this Dhanwantari Gayatri Mantra:

```
Om Vasudevaya Vidmahe
Vaidhyarajaya Dhimahi
Tanno Dhanvantri Prachodayat
```

This Mantra can be found on Internet, but also I have this book [Исцеляющие мантры в Аюрведе (Russian Edition)](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B&client=firefox-b-d&tbm=isch&sxsrf=ALeKk03i8ypSZ_g8IFBqGmntrm8p--Rd8Q:1600244061948&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjC0fbWne3rAhUXAhAIHdvZAp8Q_AUIDCgC&biw=1598&bih=1214&dpr=1.2#imgrc=DqFRlz54pl_GEM), where this Mantra is a bit different:

```
Om Vasudevaya Vidmahe
Djagad-rakshaya Dhimahi
Tanno Dhanvantri Prachodayat
```

Sorry for maybe wrong spelling as in this book Mantra is written using Cyrillic.
What is the difference between `Vaidhyarajaya Dhimahi` and `Djagad-rakshaya Dhimahi`? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! Here is the related Q: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8455/12304

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, I already red this article, but it does not answer my question.

Comment: Many times a particular deity has more than one Gayatri mantra and all of them are correct. In this case both can be correct. @wotesi

Comment: [Dhimahi](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/dhimahi) means to meditate upon .. vaidyarajaya dhimahi=we meditate upon Vaidyaraja (king among all physicians), Jagad rakshaya dhimahi= we meditate upon one who protects the Jagad (world/universe). @wotesi